# Batch to find string (contained in textlist.txt) in other .txt files in directory and copy value from .txt to new one

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, copy, find

have a problem with finding a batch to find and copy strings which are listed in textlist.txt from text files. Is it possible to make                                  batch witch should find all values (from textlist) in text files in directory and copy all of this values to new file.
I have directory with:

textlist.txt contains:

- 3010
- 3020
- 3030
  ....

and other directory with txt files:

3010.txt contains tab delimited for example:

- 3010 a1
- 3011 b1
- 3012 c1
  ....

3020.txt contains for example:

- 3020 a4
- 3021 b3
- 3022 g5
  ....

3030.txt contains for example:

- 3030 h5 g7
- 3031 f2
- 3032 t4
  ....

and other 3040.txt, 3050.txt etc.

I need result txt file like this.

- 3010 a1 { this string becams from 3010.txt but is possible that it can be found in other txt file.}
- 3020 a4 { this string becams from 3010.txt but is possible that it can be found in other txt file.}
- 3030 h5 g7 { this string becams from 3010.txt but is possible that it can be found in other txt file.}

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The following will produce a file containing matches across all the files for all the input lines:

```
@ECHO OFF
>results.txt (
  FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN (textlist.txt) DO (
    FIND "%%i" files\*.txt | FINDSTR /v "^---- ^$"
  )
)
```

It works like this:

- `FIND` takes an input line, searches the specified files for it and prints the results, which are piped to `FINDSTR`.
- `FINDSTR` removes the ‘noise’ produced by `FIND` (empty lines and lines like `------ filename.txt`) and prints the rest.
- The parsed result is printed on the *standard output*, which is redirected to `results.txt` for the entire loop.

If, as per your comment, you need additionally to create another file containing the lines that had no matches, you could modify the above script like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
>results.txt 2>notinfile.txt (
  FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN (textlist.txt) DO (
    (FIND "%%i" files\*.txt || (ECHO %%i) 1>&2) | FINDSTR /v "^---- ^$"
  )
)
```

The logic is mostly the same except when `FIND` gets no matches for the input line. In that case the search term is printed on the *standard error* (`ECHO … 1>&2`). The standard output of `FIND` is still gets piped to `FINDSTR` and, as it contains *only* noise in this case, `FINDSTR` produces nothing.

So, the loop produces results both on the standard output and on the standard error, each time depending on the result of `FIND`. The standard output is redirected to `results.txt`, like in the previous version, and the standard error is redirected to `notinfile.txt`.

**UPDATE**

The second script has got a tiny flaw which may or may not be serious in your situation, depending on how you are going to use the `notinfile.txt` file. The flaw consists in an extra space being added to the end of every value that goes to `notinfile.txt`.

Whether it is a bug or an artefact of some sort, I don't know, but I found out that if I store the results of `FIND` to a temporary file and later load them from it into `FINDSTR`, no extra space is produced. I couldn't find any other way to fix the extra space issue, so here's the modified version:

```
@ECHO OFF
>results.txt 2>notinfile.txt (
  FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN (textlist.txt) DO (
    FIND "%%i" files\*.txt >tmpResults || (ECHO %%i) 1>&2
    FINDSTR /v "^---- ^$" <tmpResults
  )
)
DEL tmpResults 2>NUL
```

**UPDATE 2** (following additional comments)

Since values in the files are tab delimited, you can include the delimiter into the search string, just after the searched term, to prevent matching `aaa` with e.g. `aaa/bbb`. So instead of

```
FIND "%%i"
```

you would have

```
FIND "%%i   "
```

where the wide space after `%%i` is the tab character.

And I would also like to suggest an alternative version of the `FINDSTR` command. As you are searching for just one term, you can change this:

```
FINDSTR /v "^---- ^$"
```

to simply this:

```
FINDSTR "%%i"
```

Comment: I don't know why but anyone from this scripts doesn't work. I've tried to use it with only one .txt file with two records and with two positions on textlist. It starts but take along time without finish.

Comment: @Artec: Not sure what it could be. I tested this on Windows XP SP3 before posting.

Comment: @ Andriy M: Ok it was my mistake. I use W7 and it works great. I changed files\*.txt on C:\folder\*.txt and its ok but I have to check this because in result.txt I see more records than in textlist.txt. Maybe this values are duplicated in my text files. When I check it I'll post results. Thanks for help.

Comment: @ Andriy M : I have checked this script. In txt files i have strings with dots, underscores and slashes like this 104_2.0003.11/1, 08_5.0013.24, 08_5.0013.240/1, 08_5.0013.240/2 . And when i look for 08_5.0013.24 (in textlist.txt) I've got 08_5.0013.24 and 08_5.0013.240/1 and 08_5.0013.240/2 (all values which contains  08_5.0013.24) etc. in results.txt. Is it possible to modify the script for looking only values inserted to textlis.txt

Comment: @Artec: Can there be anything after those values on the same lines (in the target files)? I mean, will the matching line look just like `08_5.0013.24` (just the searched value) or will it be somehing like `08_5.0013.24 qwerty` (i.e. the searched value, then a space, then something else)?

Comment: @ Andriy M : Sample content of .txt file: (3 columns with tab delimited)
08_5.0013.24 310060.65 460487.07
08_5.0013.240/2 312560.65 462187.07

Comment: @ Andriy M : Sample content of textlist.txt:
08_5.0013.24
Sample content of results.txt:
08_5.0013.24 310060.65 460487.07
08_5.0013.240/2 312560.65 462187.07
I need only first line from results.txt because only this is included in textlist.txt.

Comment: @Artec: Then you can search for `%%i<tab>` instead of just `%%i`, where `<tab>` stands for the tab character. See my update for more details.

Comment: @ Andriy M: Hi, when I changed this with your topic I get a path to the files in results (not values). I can stay with script before update of code. It's not a big problem to have duplicate values in file. I thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Artec: If you meant my last suggestion, then yes, I made a silly mistake indeed: forgot to remove `/v` from `FINDSTR /v "%%i"` after copy-pasting. It should be `FINDSTR "%%i"` actually. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use FOR command to execute a command for each line in a file (with the /F switch).  Use FIND to search the files.  Here is a sample that demonstrates their use.

FIND reports matches but also adds a line starting with "----" to show which file the match was found in.  Thats why the first FOR dumps to a temp file.  The second for treats as comments any line that starts with "-" and thus filters out that information from FIND.  If you run the batch more than once it will delete any previous results.txt file.

It is important that the textlist.txt file is NOT in the same folder as the search folder, otherwise its contents will be included in the results.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set searchFolder=C:\theFolder

del tempResults.txt >nul 2>nul
del results.txt >nul 2>nul

for /F "delims=" %%i in (textlist.txt) do find "%%i" %searchFolder%\*.txt >> tempResults.txt
for /F "delims=" "eol=-" %%i in (tempResults.txt) do echo %%i >>results.txt
del tempResults.txt >nul 2>nul

endlocal
```

Comment: Idea is ok but is something wrong. It doesn't work. I'll see message "file is using by other process" and "system cant find results.txt"

Comment: I modified the script to ignore delimiters.  The above script works on my Windows 7 machine with the three files you described above and their contents.  Did you change "set searchFolder=..." to point to where your search files are?  Make sure that folder is not the same as where the textlist.txt or the batch file is - and make sure to leave off any trailing backspaces.

Comment: It could also be just one line: `> results.txt (for /F "delims=" %%i in (textlist.txt) do (find "%%i" C:\folder\*.txt | findstr /v "^---- ^$"))`.

Comment: @Andriy M is it possible do second part of this script which show me values not contained in .*txt files and is it possible to do it in one batch because in result I need two separate files. One results.txt like above and second notinfile.txt with strings wchch wasn't found in txt files? Thanks a lot.